# Question without auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

Consider the conversation below. Is the last question correct?

> A: What did you think about it?
>   B: I thought it was terrible.
>   A: **You thought it was terrible?**

It sounds a bit strange without the auxiliary verb.

Comment: This coversation is in a lesson of Englishtown, at Level 5, Unit 5.

Comment: Which makes it off topic as homework ;-)

Comment: It is not homework. I just thought that question is strange. This conversation is in a lesson. I don't know if that sentense is correct.

Comment: [Do support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) is fairly straightforward general reference. The question without do support is actually just an echo of statement B, to confirm content, or request additional explanation. No inversion; no do support.

Comment: @ScotM I know it. So, the last sentence is wrong, right? Because this conversation is a part of a entire conversation between two native speakers.

Comment: The question is legitimate grammatically.

Comment: The only problem I've got with the English involved is with your 'It sounds a bit strange without the auxiliary verb.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am learning English. Can you show to me how should I say that sentense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sentence is grammatical. I've a problem with what you say, not how you say it: I don't find 'You thought it was terrible?' in any way odd (when used in conversation).

Comment: We -- English's learners -- have learned that we must to use 'Do' in kind of questions like that. So, can I use that questions without "Do" auxiliary? It's a thing very strange for me, because I've never saw nothing like that.

Comment: The response to "I thought the play was terrible." of "You thought it was terrible?" is certainly acceptable and common in conversation. It is known, for obvious reasons, as an 'echo question' {see [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-echo-and-checking-questions)}. There are also declarative questions (You're going to the supermarket tomorrow?), {see [Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Declarative-Question-term.htm)} again not using the normal do-support.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common English locution to report someone's words back to them in indirect speech with the rising inflection indicated by the question mark.  It indicates some incredulousness:  "I can't believe you thought is was that bad."  Or an indication that the questioner misunderstood what he heard.

The straightforward question with the auxiliary "do" --  "Did you think it was terrible?" after an expression of distaste will likely get the response "Didn't you hear me the first time?

Comment: It can also indicate that that the questioner wants the other person to elaborate. "You thought it was terrible?" might mean "Go on; why did you think it was terrible?"